# Excel VBA copy entire row to new sheet based off cell data

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to Excel VBA and need some help.  I have a list of data that I would like to copy to a new sheet based off the data in column B and copy the entire row to a new sheet of the same name.

```
Column B
2nd Black
1st Black
1st Brown
2nd Brown
3rd Brown
```

I've changed my code and came up with this.  Everything Is working.  Thanks for your help.

```
Sub create_role()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("master")

j = 11
k = 11
l = 11
m = 11

For Each c In Source.Range("b11:b110")
    If (c = "5th Black" Or c = "4th Black" Or c = "3rd Black" Or c = "2nd Black" Or c = "1st Black" Or c = "Jr. Black") Then
       Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BLACK")
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
    ElseIf c = "1st Brown" Then
        Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("1ST BROWN")
        Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(k)
        k = k + 1
    ElseIf c = "2nd Brown" Then
        Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("2ND BROWN")
        Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(l)
        l = l + 1
    ElseIf c = "3rd Brown" Then
        Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("3RD BROWN")
        Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(m)
        m = m + 1
    End If

    j = j + 1

Next c
```

End Sub

Comment: I think you have `If c.Value = Worksheet.CodeName Then` backwards. Also you didn't define `Target`?

Comment: Also, I think your counter `j` needs to happen after the `End If` but before the `Next`.

Comment: @findwindow Thank you.  How would I define the target since there are 3 of them?

Comment: I switch the c.value = worksheet.codename and i'm still gtting an object not defined error.

Comment: You would need to declare 3 different targets then. When I said backwards, I mean your logic. You need to loop through your codenames, not the range.

Comment: @Brian - if you provide a better description of what `Target` is supposed to be, I could provide you with modified code. So far, I know it's a range and there should be three of them ... Is it part of the Master worksheet? Is it part of a different worksheet?

Comment: Instead of using `j` for all four versions of `Target` use `Target.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1`. Or use individual counters. e.g. `i` for BLACK, `j` for 1ST BROWN, `k` for 2ND BROWN, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Any references to a worksheet by its Worksheet [.Name property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196974.aspx) is case insensitive and you can take advantage of that.

```
Option Explicit

Sub create_role()
    Dim src As String, trgtws As String, c As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("master")

        For Each c In .Range(.Cells(11, "B"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
            trgtws = vbNullString
            src = StrConv(c.Value2, vbProperCase)
            Select Case True
                Case src Like "*Black"
                    trgtws = "BLACK"
                Case src Like "*Brown"
                    trgtws = UCase(src)
                Case Else
                    'do nothing
            End Select

            If CBool(Len(trgtws)) Then
                With .Parent.Worksheets(trgtws)
                    c.EntireRow.Copy _
                      Destination:=.Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, "A")
                End With
            End If
        Next c

    End With
End Sub
```

I've changed your criteria method to a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx) that should make expansion to more conditions easier but your `IF ... ElseIf ... End If` could be used here.

The destination location assumes that there is some sort of column header label in B10 of each worksheet if there are no values below that.